# LDAP on ec2 - security concerns

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, ldap

I'm new to LDAP and would like to install it on AWS ec2. However, I'm concerned about exposing the required ports to public and was wondering if there is a 'safe' way to go about it. I would figure if I exposed the LDAP port publicly, someone can connect and attempt to read the LDAP database.

What is the best practice for setting up LDAP on ec2? I'm attempting to use FreeIPA on Cent OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set public VPC and private VPC with different security groups (for inbound and outbound ports management). Public VPC for the instances which need face to public, such as web servers. Private VPC are internal servers, such as application and database servers. Your ldap server should be put in private VPC (in fact, it depends on, you need give more details). You need open the inbound port (such as 636/389) from  webservers to ldap servers.

You also need install a VPN (such as `openvpn`) to guarantee only users from nominated IPs can login your environment (include public and private VPC).

Comment: Thanks, this is extremely close to the implementation I ended up going with. I created a VPC using the VPC template for public + private subnets and created my FreeIPA server in the private. I intend on having my web servers in the private subnet so it has direct access to the directory and using the NAT/load balancer against the web server ports.